# How to allow permissions to patch and delete for author and admin at the same time?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a little bit lost how can I at the same time write `has_object_permission`(For author) and `has_permission`(For admin)in the same class, won’t one overwrite another? Or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Use only `has_object_permission`. I assume you want the admin to have permission for all objects and a user to only have permission if they are the author. So if the user is an admin or the user is the author of the object return True

Comment: by creating two categories where author may fall on category 2,while staff category 1,Then create permisions on the users category